# prevent save and download images in my website using woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, web, woocommerce

how to prevent user from open or download images in woocommerce plugin in my website ? 
knowing that I'm using zoom magnifier plugin

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps I hope below steps will help you to prevent download images in WooCommerce.

1. Go to the WordPress control panel and go to “Plugins” menu and press the button “Add New”.
2. Go to the tab “Upload” and choose the file “Prevent_Content_Copy_and_Image_Save_Protection.zip”, click the button “Upload” to get the file uploaded.
3. Lock up the plugin, and click “Activate” to get it active.